# Display the profile data in accordance with the login id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a "login" and "profile" table in my database.

login =['id_login, username, password, etc...']

profile =['id_profile, id_login, fullname, address, etc...']

Model

```
function my_model(){

    $this->db->select('fullname, address, A.name_table, B.name_text');
    $this->db->from('profile');
    $this->db->join('A','A.id_table=profile.id_table');
    $this->db->join('B','B.id_text=profile.id_text');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
function my_controller(){

    $data['view_profil']= $this->model->my_model();
    $this->tmp->screen('my_view', $data);
}
```

What I want to ask. How do I display the profile data in accordance with the login id? How its implementation in my view file? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the ID of the successfully logged in profile and store in a session and use it in the query (as a where clause) to retrieve only the record of that specific profile.

```
$this->db->select('fullname, address, A.name_table, B.name_text');
$this->db->from('profile');
$this->db->where('id', $this->sessoin->userdata('Profile_ID');
```

Then get the array and display it in the view!

```
echo $view_profil['fullname'];
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I can display the data in the page view, but when I use the command 'where' in my model, the data can't be displayed and error messages appear. Unsolved problem is displaying profile data from profile table in accordance with the login account (login table). Are there any suggestions for me again? Thank you very much for the help.